# SRSS xml format

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

is there any settings for output xml from RS to format output xml like when you opened xml in browser(every node on new row..)?
When I open output xml in text editor there only one long line..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never tried this, but the documentation seems to suggest you can alter the rendering behaviour with the [XML Device Information Settings](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154691.aspx), one of which is the option `Indented` which is defaulted to `false` (thus producing the compressed XML).

It looks like you can change this behaviour for the whole server by [changing the RSReportServer.config file](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms156281.aspx), or for an individual report by [adding some query string parameters to the end of the URL](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms155397.aspx).

Comment: It's working! Thankyou!
just change
<code> <Extension Name="XML" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.XmlDataReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering"/> </code>
on<code>
<Extension Name="XML" Type="Microsoft.ReportingServices.Rendering.DataRenderer.XmlDataReport,Microsoft.ReportingServices.DataRendering">   
   <Configuration>
    <DeviceInfo>
     <Indented>true</Indented>      
    </DeviceInfo>
   </Configuration>   
   </Extension></code>

Comment: Great!  I see you haven't marked any answers as accepted before - you should consider doing this (obviously only if the answer was helpful) as it helps the community recognise the correct answer.